# Terraform for_each on an indexed resource

Tags: terraform

I have a set of resources that need to be created based on a var `service_count` which defines the amount of modules (and related resources) that will be deployed. I need an `aws_acm_certificate` and `aws_route53_record` for each of the modules created.

**In other words**, if `var.service_count` is `0`, then none of the below resources should be created. If it's `1`, then one of each resource is created.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "foo" {
  domain_name               = "foo.${var.base_domain}"
  subject_alternative_names = null
  validation_method         = "DNS"
  count                     = var.service_count

  options {
    certificate_transparency_logging_preference = "ENABLED"
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}-foo"
    Environment = var.env
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  for_each = {
    for dv in aws_acm_certificate.foo.domain_validation_options : dv.domain_name => {
      name   = dv.resource_record_name
      type   = dv.resource_record_type
      record = dv.resource_record_value
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  type            = each.value.type
  ttl             = 60
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.foo]
}

module "foo" {
  count    = var.service_count
  cert_arn = aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].arn

  # omitting a bunch of module vars that don't apply to the quesion
}
```

Since the route53 record is using `for_each` (based on the [doc example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#referencing-domain_validation_options-with-for_each-based-resources)), I can't seem to get this to work.

---

When trying as-is, it errors with:

```
Because aws_acm_certificate.foo has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
     aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index]
```

Adding `[count.index]`, as the error message suggests, like this:

```
for dv in aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options ...
```

does not work because `count` is not set on the `aws_route53_record` resource.

This'll just throw an error like this:

```
Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
[...]
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

---

If I try:

```
for dv in aws_acm_certificate.foo[*].domain_validation_options
```

It results in:

```
Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?
```

---

I have tried using `count` in the `aws_route53_record` block, like this:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  count = var.service_count

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options.resource_record_name
  records         = [aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options.resource_record_value]
  type            = aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options.resource_record_type
  ttl             = 60
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.foo]
}
```

This results in errors such as:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on test.tf line 29, in resource "aws_route53_record" "foo":
│   29:   name            = aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options.resource_record_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_acm_certificate.foo is tuple with 1 element
│     │ count.index is 0
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?
╵
```

Same error throws for each of the name, records, and type fields in the resource. The [official docs state](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#referencing-domain_validation_options-with-for_each-based-resources) to use `for_each` which is why it's being used in the original post snippet.

---

I'm guessing that I'm thinking about this all wrong, but I can't seem two wrap my head around how this should be written.

NOTE: *It is not feasible for this wider use-case that these resources are added to the module*

Comment: "does not work because count is not set on the aws_route53_record resource." Please update the question with evidence to support this claim. This is untrue as the question is currently written. Also update with a clarification as to "does not work".

Comment: Hi thanks. However, "count is not set on the aws_route53_record resource" is a true statement. It's using for_each, not count. For your second point: I've added the error message to the post per your request. Appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Ok I see now you are misinterpreting the error message, and that was the source of our confusion. However, at second glance it is now clear the error is from somewhere else in the code. You may want to begin searching elsewhere for a reference to the exported resource attribute of `aws_acm_certificate.foo` without an element index, as that is throwing the error.

Comment: A combination of for_each and count will almost never work if you use both of them to iterate/loop over, If you could please include the #stuf [pending code ]also I can try it in my local env. 
`aws_acm_certificate.foo.domain_validation_options` should be something `aws_acm_certificate[index].foo.domain_validation_options ` or you can take complete object out `aws_acm_certificate.foo` and then do some hacky stuff

Comment: Thanks @ishuar for the advice and help - I've added more to the snippets as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@emmdee , This is not the only way but works, please use the below code. I have used count with static value(simplicity) but in mentioned [Github Repo](https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/aws/deadly-count-for-each-combo) below used a variable and then on that basis decided the count. So you can adjust accordingly.

### Terraform Code

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "foo" {

  count                     = 2
  domain_name               = "foo.${local.base_domain[count.index]}"
  subject_alternative_names = null
  validation_method         = "DNS"

  options {
    certificate_transparency_logging_preference = "ENABLED"
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${local.env}-${local.base_domain[count.index]}"
    Environment = local.env
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

locals {

  env         = "dev"
  base_domain = ["foo.com", "bar.com"]

  flatten_acm_object = flatten(
    [for first_step_value in aws_acm_certificate.foo :
      [for second_step_value in first_step_value.domain_validation_options : second_step_value]
  ])

}

resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  for_each = { for domain in local.flatten_acm_object : domain.domain_name => domain }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.resource_record_name
  records         = [each.value.resource_record_value]
  type            = each.value.resource_record_type
  ttl             = 60
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.foo]
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "public" {
  name = "foo.com"
}
```

For a more structured example please refer to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/aws/deadly-count-for-each-combo) (I created).

### Generated Plan For Reference

```bash
➜  random_local_tests git:(main) ✗ tf plan                                                                                                                        <aws:sre>

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_acm_certificate.foo[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_acm_certificate" "foo" {
      + arn                       = (known after apply)
      + domain_name               = "foo.foo.com"
      + domain_validation_options = [
          + {
              + domain_name           = "foo.foo.com"
              + resource_record_name  = (known after apply)
              + resource_record_type  = (known after apply)
              + resource_record_value = (known after apply)
            },
        ]
      + id                        = (known after apply)
      + key_algorithm             = (known after apply)
      + not_after                 = (known after apply)
      + not_before                = (known after apply)
      + pending_renewal           = (known after apply)
      + renewal_eligibility       = (known after apply)
      + renewal_summary           = (known after apply)
      + status                    = (known after apply)
      + subject_alternative_names = [
          + "foo.foo.com",
        ]
      + tags                      = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "dev-foo.com"
        }
      + tags_all                  = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "dev-foo.com"
        }
      + type                      = (known after apply)
      + validation_emails         = (known after apply)
      + validation_method         = "DNS"

      + options {
          + certificate_transparency_logging_preference = "ENABLED"
        }
    }

  # aws_acm_certificate.foo[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_acm_certificate" "foo" {
      + arn                       = (known after apply)
      + domain_name               = "foo.bar.com"
      + domain_validation_options = [
          + {
              + domain_name           = "foo.bar.com"
              + resource_record_name  = (known after apply)
              + resource_record_type  = (known after apply)
              + resource_record_value = (known after apply)
            },
        ]
      + id                        = (known after apply)
      + key_algorithm             = (known after apply)
      + not_after                 = (known after apply)
      + not_before                = (known after apply)
      + pending_renewal           = (known after apply)
      + renewal_eligibility       = (known after apply)
      + renewal_summary           = (known after apply)
      + status                    = (known after apply)
      + subject_alternative_names = [
          + "foo.bar.com",
        ]
      + tags                      = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "dev-bar.com"
        }
      + tags_all                  = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "dev-bar.com"
        }
      + type                      = (known after apply)
      + validation_emails         = (known after apply)
      + validation_method         = "DNS"

      + options {
          + certificate_transparency_logging_preference = "ENABLED"
        }
    }

  # aws_route53_record.foo["foo.bar.com"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
      + allow_overwrite = true
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = (known after apply)
      + records         = (known after apply)
      + ttl             = 60
      + type            = (known after apply)
      + zone_id         = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_route53_record.foo["foo.foo.com"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
      + allow_overwrite = true
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = (known after apply)
      + records         = (known after apply)
      + ttl             = 60
      + type            = (known after apply)
      + zone_id         = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_route53_zone.public will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_zone" "public" {
      + arn                 = (known after apply)
      + comment             = "Managed by Terraform"
      + force_destroy       = false
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + name                = "foo.com"
      + name_servers        = (known after apply)
      + primary_name_server = (known after apply)
      + tags_all            = (known after apply)
      + zone_id             = (known after apply)
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick. Flattening it as a local var first is exactly what was needed. Using your sample code as an example I was able to solve the problem!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but my first thought is to rewrite aws_route53_record to use count rather than a for each

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  count = var.service_count

  # stuff
  # when you need to reference resource_record_name use this style of access:
  
  name = aws_acm_certificate.foo[count.index].domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried with count and added the snippet + error to the original post. Here is the [doc reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#referencing-domain_validation_options-with-for_each-based-resources) using the for_each to dig into the nested objects.

Comment: domain_validation_options is a set https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#domain_validation_options maybe indexing this would fix it, do you always expect one in the set or could it be multiple? Ive amended my answer with this in mind